# Android, PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and Sleep Mode

Tags: android, connection, sleep, keep-alive

I wrote an application with one activity and remote service. The main goal of this service is keep net connection with remote TCP server. I use in activity PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to prevent system going in sleep mode. But after about twenty minutes when screen is off, the connection stops. It looks it starts unfortunately sleep mode and cut connection. When I turn on my device connection is starting again (my codę detects error and try to set connection again). 
Is a better way to keep connection whole time? I do not have to worry about battery - the device is plug in charge all time. The priority is keep connection. 
Could somebody give advice how to resolve my problem?

Regards Artik

Comment: If the device is always plugged in and you don't care about battery, try a full wakelock.

Comment: What sort of connection? If WiFi, are you using a `WifiLock` as well?

Comment: It is GSM(GPRS) connection. After some command from server device has to do certain things ie. play sound etc.

Comment: What sort of heartbeat are you using to keep your socket alive?

Comment: Device sends every 7seconds small package to the server to keep connection. And server does similar sensing proces to device.

Comment: How are you starting your service - STICKY or NOT_STICKY?

Comment: I'm starting my service not_sticky